# Oracle SQL: Alias Column and Sum with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have an alias column `m` and a sum function.  I know I cannot group by `m` in the top query because the `SELECT` has not been executed. I have found that I am able to do this query if I remove the `m` column, but I need this column to appear in the query.

So I have tried to put a `SELECT` and `FROM(` in front of the query.

```
select jobno,m,total
from (
  select j.jobno,
         sum(r.amtfc) total,
         decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno) m
from job j,
     jobother jo,
     revenue r,
     fmparty f
where j.voidby is  null 
 and  j.unid=jo.job_unid 
 and  j.unid=r.job_unid 
  and r.invdocno is null 
  and f.partyid=r.billing_partyid 
)
group by jobno, m
```

but this is giving me back

> "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Your query makes no sense because you mix aggregates and regular columns in the same select clause.  Maybe you should tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a revenue table that is itemized on individual charges and I have job table.  I want the revenue table to only show the total.  from the job table I have 'm' because I want to display the consolno if it exists and the shpno if it does not exist.  i hope this makes a little more sense.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0):

From  about 'ORA-00979'

> You tried to execute a SELECT statement that included a GROUP BY function (ie: MIN Function, MAX Function, SUM Function, COUNT Function) and an expression in the SELECT list that was not in the GROUP BY clause.

I think your select might be something like

```
SELECT j.jobno jobno,
       decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno) m,
       sum(r.amtfc) total
FROM job j,jobother jo,revenue r,fmparty f
WHERE j.voidby is  null and  j.unid=jo.job_unid and  
      j.unid=r.job_unid and r.invdocno is null and
      f.partyid=r.billing_partyid
GROUP BY j.jobno, decode(j.consolno,null,j.shpno,j.consolno)
```

Comment: Thanks this works!  I just needed to not group by 'm' and group by the decode....

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper, explicit `join` syntax!

You can simplify your query to:

```
select j.jobno, sum(r.amtfc) as total,
       coalesce(j.consolno, j.consolno) as m
from job j join
     jobother jo
     on j.unid = jo.job_unid join
     revenue r
     on j.unid = r.job_unid join
     fmparty f
     on f.partyid = r.billing_partyid
where j.voidby is null and r.invdocno is null 
group by jobno, coalesce(j.consolno, j.consolno)
```